# Correct way to set StatusBar color on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

I have made a blank starter app with default theme (Ionic 5).

For Android, this is how it looks. This looks quite odd, as I was expecting a darker version of the primary color to be used as the color of the status bar.

[image]

**The status bar is black. What is the correct way to set the color of the status bar to some other color?**

I have tried the following things:

1. StatusBar

   `this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');`
2. StatusBar color in preferences

   `<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#457492" />`

But none of these work. For now, I have resorted to doing this through the Android project's MainActivity.

`getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.status_bar_color));`

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  navigate: any;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ff371d');
      this.sideMenu();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Number one is correct , but just remove this.statusbar.deafultStyle() since it may be doing a conflect with this method.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Add your app.compoent.ys in you question.

Comment: this.statusBar.backgroundColorByName("red");   try this, although backgrounscolorbyhexstring should work normaly but lets see where is the bug, and for statusbar.defaultstyle its for color of icons or text in status bar to be black or white

Comment: try: `this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.statusBar.styleBlackTranslucent();` in side `initializeApp()`

Comment: Didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can set Statusbar color in your parent theme also.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       ...
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ffffff</item>
       ...

    </style>
```

Comment: This alone doesn't work. This only changes the status bar color during the splash screen, not after that.

Comment: I've tried in my app and it works. kindly check in other screen `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.status_bar_color));` will override the style effect.

Comment: Doesn't work even if I remove this `getWindow()`... call.

Answer (score 0):

Do you change the color after `platform.ready()`?

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#A9C23F');
}
```

I did not change anything in the config and this is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the style.xml:

```
item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

or

```
item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0000</item>
```

[image: ***Click here to open image***]